# How to convert String to Datetime including time part in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012

I want to convert below string to DateTime in SQL.

```
20140601152943767
```

I know `convert(date,'20140601152943767')` this but I want time part also.

Above function only returns me Date part.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: May be convert to 2014-06-01 15:29:43.767 than cast to datetime?

Comment: I am also not able to convert this 152943767 Time also. can you have any idea how to convert string to time atleast

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use following solution:

```
SELECT CONVERT(DATETIME, STUFF(STUFF(STUFF(STUFF('20140601152943767', 9, 0, ' '), 12, 0, ':') , 15, 0, ':'), 18, 0, '.'))
```

Note #0: All those `STUFF` calls will convert source strings from `20140601152943767` to `20140601 15:29:43.767`.

Note #1: `SELECT STUFF('abcef', 4, 1, 'DDD')` will replace substring starting from index 4 with a length of 1 char (`e`) with `DDD` -> `abcDDDf`

Note #2: `SELECT STUFF('abcef', 4, 0, 'DDD')` returns `abcDDDef`

Answer (score 2):

You can try lik ethis:

```
select
concat(convert(date,LEFT('20140601152943767',8)), ' ' , Convert(time,Dateadd(SECOND,
        Right('20140601152943767',2)/1,
        Dateadd(MINUTE,
                Right('20140601152943767',4)/100,
                Dateadd(hour,
                        Right('20140601152943767',6)/10000,
                        '1900-01-01')))) )
 as myDate
```

Output:

```
2014-06-01 22:38:07.0000000
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, first of all - you need conversion not to `date` but to `datetime` type.

Second - you should always specify format as mentioned:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928(v=sql.120).aspx

e.g. 
`select convert(datetime, '20140501', 112)`

3 - there is no such format supported for your value demonstrated, so you have to modify your value yo something like `yyyy-mm-ddThh:mi:ss.mmm` (iso) or to make custom conversion with `substring` and so on.

```
;WITH myvalues AS (
    SELECT '20140601152943767' value
)
SELECT
    convert(date, LEFT(mv.value, 8), 112),
    cast(STUFF(STUFF(STUFF(STUFF(mv.[value], 1, 8, ''), 7, 0, '.'), 5, 0, ':'), 3, 0, ':') AS TIME)
FROM myvalues mv
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This one

```
declare @datetime varchar(20) = '20140601152943767'

select convert(varchar(20),convert(date,LEFT(@datetime,8))) + ' ' + substring(RIGHT(@datetime,9), 1, 2)
+ ':' + substring(RIGHT(@datetime,9), 3, 2)
+ ':' + substring(RIGHT(@datetime,9), 5, 2) 
+ '.' + substring(RIGHT(@datetime,9), 7, 3)
```

Answer (score 0):

I know some might argue that this is not the best way , but still it's an alternative.Few people have already used convert and stuff functions .
Try this out.Easy to understand.Also test your subqueries.

```
select y1||'-'||M1||'-'||d1||' '||h1||':'||mi||':'||s1||':'||f1 as xdate
                           from
                           ( 
                           select  substr('20140601152943767',1,4) Y1 from dual
                           ),
                           (
                           select  substr('20140601152943767',5,2)M1  from dual
                           ),
                           (
                           select  substr('20140601152943767',7,2) d1 from dual
                           ),
                           (
                           select  substr('20140601152943767',9,2) h1 from dual
                           ),
                            (
                           select  substr('20140601152943767',11,2) mi from dual
                           ),
                            (
                           select  substr('20140601152943767',13,2) s1 from dual
                           ),
                            (
                           select  substr('20140601152943767',15,3) f1 from dual
                           )
```

Output:

2014-06-01 15:29:43.767